# Choose implementation at compile time in F#

Tags: f#, compile-time

Most programming languages have some way of choosing an implementation at compile-time based on types. Function overloading is a common way of doing this. Using templates (in C++ or D possibly with constraits) is another option.

But in F#, I cannot find out how to do this without using class methods, and thus loosing some nice properties like currying.

```
let f (a:int) =
```

Gives `Duplicate definition of 'f'`

F# has [statically resolved type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd548046.aspx), but I don't how I can use this..

```
let f (a:^T) =
    match T with
```

Gives `The value or constructor of T is not defined` at `match T`

```
let f (a:^T) =
    match a with
    | :> int as i ->
```

Gives `Unexpected symbol ':>' in expression`

```
let f (a:^T) =
    match ^a with
    | :> int as i ->
```

Gives `Unexpected infix operator in expression`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write a function that behaves differently for different types and is an ordinary F# function, then static member constraints let you do that. However, if you want to write idiomatic F# code, then there are other options:

- [Here is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868327/f-type-constraints-and-overloading-resolution) showing how you can use static member constraints to do this
- F# collections use different module for each type, so there is `Array.map`, `List.map`, `Seq.map` etc. This is idiomatic style for functional F# libraries.
- [FSharpChart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297116(v=vs.100).aspx) is an example of a library that uses overloaded methods. Note that you can use static methods, so you can write `Chart.Line [ ... ]` and it will pick the right overload.
- If you want to write generic numeric code, then [I recently wrote a tutorial that covers this topic](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx).

So, I would be a bit careful before using static constraints - it is not entirely idiomatic (e.g. not commonly used in standard libraries) and so it may cause some confusion. But it is quite powerful and certainly useful.

The key is that simply following patterns that work well in other languages might not give you the best results in F#. If you can provide a concrete example of what you're trying to do, then you might get a better results.